# How are windows programs installed?

Tags: windows, installation

This looks like a common question. But I was not able to find answer for it. When we try to install windows programs, what exactly happens? What files are copied where? What is written in the registry?

Comment: This question is too broad. Have you done some research on this? What did you find? What specific parts were confusing?

Comment: This question is too broad. What files are copied to what locations depends entirely on the application, and so does what registry values are written to what location. It is possible to run a native Win32 application that consists of nothing but the executable itself, that doesn't have to do anything with the registry. It is also possible to install an application that requires hundreds or thousands of files put in many locations that also requires dozens of registry entries for its operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Most programs come with an installation program named Setup.exe or Install.exe. When you install a program, the installation program usually does the following:**

- Looks for a previous version of the program on your hard disk. If it
  finds a previous version, the program may ask whether you want to
  replace the previous version.
- Creates a folder in which to store the program files. Most
  installation programs ask where you'd like this folder. Some
  installation programs also create additional folders within this
  folder. Windows creates a folder named Program Files, usually in C:\
  (if Windows is stored in a partition or drive other than C, the
  Program Files folder is usually in the same partition). We recommend
  you install all your programs in folders within the Program Files
  folder.

> note  Some software vendors have the bad habit of installing
>   application programs in locations other than your Program Files
>   folder. You can't do much about this; the additional folders may
>   clutter up your root folder, but they don't do any harm.

- Copies the files onto your hard disk. If the program files are
  compressed, the installation program uncompresses them. Usually, the
  installation program copies most of the files into the program's
  folder, but it may also put some files into your C:\Windows,
  C:\Windows\System, or other folders.
- Checks your system for the files and hardware it needs to run. For
  example, an Internet connection program might check for a modem.
- Adds entries to the Windows Registry to tell Windows which types of
  files the program works with, which files the program is stored in,
  and other information about the program.
- Adds a command for the program to your Start | All Programs menu
  (some programs add submenus to the Start | All Programs menu to
  contain several commands). The installation program may also add a
  shortcut to your Windows desktop to make running the program easy for
  you. You can change the position on the Start menu of the command for
  the program, get rid of the command, or create a command if the
  installation program doesn't make one. You can also create a shortcut
  icon on the desktop, if the installation program hasn't done so, or
  move or delete the program's shortcut.
- Asks you a series of questions to configure the program for your
  system. The program may ask you to type additional information, like
  Internet addresses, passwords, or software license numbers. It may
  also ask which users should be able to run the program.

**Every installation program is different, because it comes with the application program, not with Windows. If your computer is connected to a LAN or to the Internet, the installation program may configure your program to connect to other computers on the network.**